# Oracle Apex - Download CSV produces an empty report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am currently using Oracle Apex version 18.2.0.00.12 on Internet Explorer on a computer running Windows 10.

I am having a problem with downloading an Interactive Grid as a CSV file.

On my Apex page I have an interactive grid and three page items. Two of the page items, P200_DATE_FROM and P200_DATE_TO, are Date Picker items. The other item is a button named "Submit" and its action is "Submit Page".

This is the query for my interactive grid:

```
select * from kat_test
where repairdate between :P200_DATE_FROM and :P200_DATE_TO;
```

There are four columns in the Interactive Grid:

Issue - Varchar2

Month - Number

Week - Number

Repairdate - Date

The only settings I changed in the Interactive Grid are the title and the SQL query.

I changed the Source of P200_DATE_FROM to PL/SQL Expression that returns the first day of the current month. It is set to be used "Only when the current value in session state is null". The expression is:

```
trunc(last_day(sysdate)-1, 'mm')
```

I changed the Source of P200_DATE_TO PL/SQL Expression that returns the current date. It is also set to be used "Only when the current value in session state is null". The expression is:

```
sysdate
```

When I run the page, it loads exactly as expected in the sense that the P200_DATE_FROM page item is populated with the first date of the current month, the P200_DATE_TO item is populated with the current date, and the interactive grid displays the correct data.

The problem: When I select Actions -> Download -> CSV, the CSV file downloads and opens as an Excel file, BUT only the header names are displayed. The cells underneath the headers are all empty. However, if I change one of the dates (or both) in the P200_DATE_FROM page item and/or the P200_DATE_TO page item and then press the submit button, the page is submitted and then when I click Actions -> Download -> CSV, the Excel file opens and all of the data is displayed perfectly (both the column headers and the data underneath the headers).

I don't understand why when I initially load the page, the CSV file for the Interactive Grid does not download correctly, but after I click the submit button the CSV file does download correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to put the name of these items in the field "Items to submit" next to your SQL. When it downloads, I think it reprocesses SQL using the values ​​of the items that are in the session. If you do not put those items there, the values ​​do not go to the session. Enter the item names separated by a comma. After that, I think any changes is necessary in your SQL

Answer (score 3):

Report's query, probably, contains a `WHERE` clause which looks like this:

```
where some_date between :P200_DATE_FROM and :P200_DATE_TO
```

Modify it so that includes `NVL` function whose second parameter reflects items' default values, i.e.

```
where some_date between nvl(:P200_DATE_FROM, trunc(last_day(sysdate)-1, 'mm'))
                    and nvl(:P200_DATE_TO, sysdate)
```

Run the page, download CSV; any improvement?

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! If you don't mind explaining, why is that edit to the query necessary to make the CSV file download correctly?

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea why it doesn't work as you expected (i.e. by setting items' default values). I hit the same *issue* and learned *hard way* how to fix it. If I knew *why*, I'd tell you but - I don't. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, Littlefoot, I appreciate the help!

Comment: I think you just need to put the name of these items in the field "Items to submit" next to your SQL. When it downloads, I think it reprocesses SQL using the values ​​of the items that are in the session. If you do not put those items there, the values ​​do not go to the session. Enter the item names separated by a comma. After that, I think any changes is necessary in you SQL...

Comment: Aha! @romeu, that makes sense. Thank you for the idea, I'll try to remember it.

Comment: This answer is helpful but not correct - @romeuBraga's comment identifies the correct answer.

Comment: I agree, @Jeffrey. If romeuBraga posts it as an answer, I'd suggest Katherine to accept it (and I'll gladly upvote it).

Comment: Jeffrey and Littlefoot, thank you all for your help! I would be happy to accept the answer by @romeuBraga if he decides to post it as such.